# Sitecore -> Select a Rendering -> Modify Tabs

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I'm trying to edit a page that I copied from an existing page.
It is set up to use the page editor.
When a user is in the page editor and selects New -> Component, a dialog pops up with the title "Select a Rendering".
From there, the user can select different content from different tabs. (see attached image)

[image]
My question is, what determines which tabs show up and how do I modify that selection?

Thanks,

Gregory

(I also posted this question on the Sitecore Developer Network)

Comment: Look at placeholder settings for the component in sitecore.

Comment: Yup, @xoail, that was it. Appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Those tabs are not a default feature in Sitecore, it looks like you are using a custom module, possibly the [Cognifide Tabbed Rendering Selector](http://www.cognifide.com/blogs/sitecore/sitecore-tabbed-select-a-rendering-dialog/). By default this module adds a new tab per folder.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently they are being grouped by the parent name as per the following line of code:

`var gruppedSublayouts = renderingOptions.Items.GroupBy(i => i.Parent.Name);`